# Vector of tables, flatbuffers C

Tags: c, vector, flatbuffers

I'm experimenting with flatbuffers, in C, just getting a feel for it. I'm having a weird issue. Well, a couple more than likely.

I *think* I'm building the flatbuffers and adding all the correct components in the correct manner. However, when I try to read a vector of tables, _vec_len(T) is returning size 0, even though when I hexdump the buffer I can clearly see the said tables being added to/removed from the buffer.

I've used more methods of getting the vector of tables to be readable than I can count. Most have ended with type mismatch compile errors. None of the ones that have actually compiled have resulted in _vec_len(T) returning anything other than 0.

I've also tried using _vec_at(0), but this causes an assertion to fail stating that the given index is out of range.

At this point, I'm either: a) missing something really simple, b) building the flatbuffer completely wrong, or c) making assumptions about how flatbuffers are built that are just plain incorrect.

I have attached my schema and source code, as well as debugging output from the program.

(I realized after posting that the code blocks dont include line numbers.)
The line that seems to be failing is `size_t hops_vec_len = TransitHop_vec_len(hopsTable);` in the C code, near the bottom. Either that, or the entire block starting at `// test_root routing` near the top is wrong.

By my understanding, using _start(B) and _end(B), everything that gets added to said component of the schema should be added to the buffer and placed into the v-tables for access automatically.

So, I'm not sure where to go. Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong/misunderstanding? Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

flatbuffers_test.fbs

```
table Ping {
    sent:uint;
}

table Pong {
    sent:uint;
}

union Type {
    Ping,
    Pong,
}

enum ServerTypes:ubyte {
    mach = 0,
    cnc,
    mill,
    press,
    drill,
    controller,
    unknown,
}

table TransitHop {
    serverID: uint64;
    serverType: ServerTypes;
}

table TransitHeader {
    from: TransitHop;
    to: TransitHop;
    hops: [TransitHop];
}

table TransitSequence {
    transitID:  uint64;
    begin:      uint8;
    current:    uint8;
    total:      uint8;
}

table TestRoot {
    type: Type;
    sequence: TransitSequence;
    routing: TransitHeader;
}

root_type TestRoot;
```

flatbuffers_test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "flatcc/support/hexdump.h"
#include "flatbuffers_test_builder.h"

// This allows us to verify result in optimized builds.
#define test_assert(x) do { if (!(x)) { assert(0); return -1; }} while(0)

int main(void) {

    flatcc_builder_t builder, *B;
    B = &builder;
    void *buff = NULL;
    size_t size;
    FILE *fh = NULL;

    flatcc_builder_init(B);

    printf("TestRoot - Routing\n\n");

    TestRoot_start_as_root(B);
    {
        // test_root type
        {
            Ping_ref_t testType = Ping_create(B, 0); // the 0 here would be the time the ping is sent

            TestRoot_type_add(B, Type_as_Ping(testType));
        }

        // test_root sequence
        {
            TransitSequence_ref_t sequence = TransitSequence_create(B, 1, 1, 1, 1);

            TestRoot_sequence_add(B, sequence);
        }

        // test_root routing
        {
            TransitHeader_start(B);
            {
                TransitHop_ref_t hopFrom = 0;
                TransitHop_ref_t hopTo = 0;
                TransitHeader_hops_start(B);
                {
                    hopFrom = TransitHop_create(B, 1, ServerTypes_mach);
                    TransitHop_create(B, 2, ServerTypes_controller);
                    TransitHop_create(B, 3, ServerTypes_controller);
                    hopTo = TransitHop_create(B, 4, ServerTypes_cnc);
                }
                TransitHop_ref_t hops = TransitHeader_hops_end(B);

                TransitHeader_from_add(B, hopFrom);
                TransitHeader_to_add(B, hopTo);
                TransitHeader_hops_add(B, hops);
            }
            TransitHeader_ref_t routing = TransitHeader_end(B);

            TestRoot_routing_add(B, routing);
        }
    }
    TestRoot_end_as_root(B);

    buff = flatcc_builder_finalize_aligned_buffer(&builder, &size);

    printf("flatbuffer size: %ld\n", size);

    TestRoot_table_t test_root = TestRoot_as_root(buff);

    test_assert(test_root != 0);

    int type_present = TestRoot_type_is_present(test_root);
    int sequence_present = TestRoot_sequence_is_present(test_root);
    int routing_present = TestRoot_routing_is_present(test_root);

    printf("    type present: %d\n", type_present);
    if (type_present == 1) {
        Type_union_type_t type = TestRoot_type_type(test_root);
        printf("\ttype: %s\n", Type_type_name(type));
    }

    printf("sequence present: %d\n", sequence_present);
    if (sequence_present == 1) {
        TransitSequence_table_t sequence = TestRoot_sequence(test_root);
        printf("\ttransitID: %ld\n", TransitSequence_transitID(sequence));
        printf("\t    begin: %d\n", TransitSequence_begin(sequence));
        printf("\t  current: %d\n", TransitSequence_current(sequence));
        printf("\t    total: %d\n", TransitSequence_total(sequence));
    }

    printf(" routing present: %d\n", routing_present);

    if (routing_present == 1) {
        TransitHeader_table_t routing = TestRoot_routing(test_root);

        TransitHop_table_t from = TransitHeader_from(routing);
        TransitHop_table_t to = TransitHeader_to(routing);
        TransitHop_vec_t hopsTable = TransitHeader_hops(routing);

        test_assert(hopsTable != 0);

        ServerTypes_enum_t serverTypeFrom = TransitHop_serverType(from);
        ServerTypes_enum_t serverTypeTo = TransitHop_serverType(to);

        printf("\tfrom: %ld\t%s\n", TransitHop_serverID(from), ServerTypes_name(serverTypeFrom));
        printf("\t  to: %ld\t%s\n", TransitHop_serverID(to), ServerTypes_name(serverTypeTo));

        int hops_present = TransitHeader_hops_is_present(routing);

        if (hops_present == 1) {
//            // this causes [Assertion `flatbuffers_vec_len(vec) > (i) && "index out of range"' failed.] ?????
//            TransitHop_table_t hopsTableZero = TransitHop_vec_at(hopsTable, 0);
//
//            test_assert(hopsTableZero == 0);


            size_t hops_vec_len = TransitHop_vec_len(hopsTable);
            printf("\thops: %lu\n", hops_vec_len);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < hops_vec_len; i++) {
                printf("\t\t%lu\n", i);
            }
        }
    }

    fh = fopen("/tmp/fbhd-test1", "w");

    if (fh == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open /tmp/fbhd-test1 for writing\n\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        hexdump(NULL, buff, size, fh);
    }

    fclose(fh);

    flatcc_builder_aligned_free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

debug1.txt

```
Program output with the vector of tables being added to the flatbuffer:

TestRoot - Routing

flatbuffer size: 188
    type present: 1
        type: Ping
sequence present: 1
        transitID: 1
            begin: 1
          current: 1
            total: 1
 routing present: 1
        from: 1 mach
          to: 4 cnc
        hops: 0



00000000  0c 00 00 00 54 45 53 54  00 00 00 00 5c ff ff ff  |....TEST....\...|
00000010  01 00 00 00 70 00 00 00  5c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |....p...\.......|
00000020  7a ff ff ff 0c 00 00 00  3c 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  |z.......<.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 96 ff ff ff  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  01 00 00 00 a6 ff ff ff  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  05 00 00 00 b6 ff ff ff  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  05 00 00 00 cc ff ff ff  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 e8 ff ff ff  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  01 01 01 00 fc ff ff ff  04 00 04 00 0c 00 0f 00  |................|
00000090  04 00 0c 00 0d 00 0e 00  06 00 0c 00 04 00 08 00  |................|
000000a0  0d 00 04 00 0c 00 0a 00  10 00 08 00 0c 00 04 00  |................|
000000b0  0c 00 14 00 04 00 08 00  0c 00 10 00              |............|





Program output without the vector of tables being added to the flatbuffer:

TestRoot - Routing

flatbuffer size: 74
    type present: 1
        type: Ping
sequence present: 1
        transitID: 1
            begin: 1
          current: 1
            total: 1
 routing present: 0



00000000  0c 00 00 00 54 45 53 54  00 00 00 00 cc ff ff ff  |....TEST........|
00000010  01 00 00 00 18 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 e8 ff ff ff  |................|
00000020  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 01 01 00 fc ff ff ff  |................|
00000030  04 00 04 00 0c 00 0f 00  04 00 0c 00 0d 00 0e 00  |................|
00000040  0a 00 10 00 04 00 08 00  0c 00                    |..........|





Program output when trying to use _vec_at(0):

TestRoot - Routing

flatbuffer size: 188
    type present: 1
        type: Ping
sequence present: 1
        transitID: 1
            begin: 1
          current: 1
            total: 1
 routing present: 1
        from: 1 mach
          to: 4 cnc
flatbuffers_test: /home/vadtec/schema/generated/flatbuffers_test_reader.h:192: TransitHop_vec_at: Assertion `flatbuffers_vec_len(vec) > (i) && "index out of range"' failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from the flatcc author.

See https://groups.google.com/g/flatbuffers/c/mjkyhbA6vS8 for the complete response.